# cannot get Ghidra's Function ID tool worked properly

Tags: ghidra

I found a difficulty in using `Ghidra`'s `Function ID` as following:

First of all, this would be some kind of testing the capability of the `Function ID`. For this reason I have a test binary file and I would try to rename as many functions as possible and later once more use this binary file and get the functions names back automatically. These are the steps:

- open a binary file (the target file), rename functions
- `Tools->Function ID->Populate FidDb from programs...`
- close the program
- open a new instance of `Ghidra` with the same binary file again
- `Tools->Function ID->Attach existing FidDb`

and hope to get the populated function names back in the new instance of the binary file but it is not the case and all functions are labeled originally such as `FUN_xxxxxxxx`.

Any help can be helpful and welcomed.

Cheers.

Comment: After attaching the FidDB, did you run auto analyze and make sure that Function ID is checked in the Anaysis options? Or run a One shot analysis (Analysis->One Shot->Function ID)?

Comment: @Erikun I did ```Analysis->One Shot->Function ID``` and worked. Thanks.